# sorting list full of objects in alphabetical order

Tags: java, arrays, object

Have an array that can hold up to 10 objects, and want to make it so that the objects, when stored, are put into alphabetical order given the name in the object. Thing is, they keep overwriting each other. I am trying to make a key-value array, but can't use any map functions or anything like that.

```
public boolean add(ItemMoretti product) {
        int i = findIndex(product.getName());
        int j = 0;
        boolean success = false;
        
        if(mySize < myItems.length) {

            for(j = (mySize - 1); j > i; j--) {
                myItems[j + 1] = myItems[j];
            }//for
            
            myItems[i] = product;
            mySize++;
            success = true;
        }//if
        return success;
    }//add
```

Here is the findIndex method as well.

```
    private int findIndex(String keyValue) {
        int x = 0;
        int index = -1;
        boolean found = false;
        
        while((x <= mySize) && (!found)) 
            if((mySize == 0) || (myItems[x].getName().compareToIgnoreCase(keyValue) == 0)) {
                index = x;
                found = true;
            }//if
            else x++;
        
        return index;   

    }//findIndex
```

Comment: "can't use any map functions" — So this is schoolwork? If so, say so. That affects the Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used bubbleSort algorithm.

```
private static ItemMoretti[] getSortedByName(ItemMoretti[] itemMorettis)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < itemMorettis.length; i++)
    {
      boolean changed = false;
      for (int j = 0; j < itemMorettis.length - 1; j++)
      {
        ItemMoretti o1 = itemMorettis[j];
        ItemMoretti o2 = itemMorettis[j + 1];
        if (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) > 0)
        {
          itemMorettis[j] = o2;
          itemMorettis[j + 1] = o1;
          changed = true;
        }
      }
      if (!changed)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    return itemMorettis;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array and for every alphabetic, you need to shift the element. Therefore, use a linked list as an efficient approach.

Here is the example how you can use it:

```
public class ItemMorettiList {
    private Node head;
    private int size;

    public ItemMorettiList() {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public boolean add(ItemMoretti product) {
        Node newNode = new Node(product);
        Node current = head;
        Node prev = null;

        while (current != null && product.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(current.data.getName()) > 0) {
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if (prev == null) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            prev.next = newNode;
        }

        newNode.next = current;
        size++;

        return true;
    }

    private class Node {
        public ItemMoretti data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(ItemMoretti data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The `ItemMorettiList` class utilizes the `Node` object to keep its linked list in sustained order. Each `Node` holds an `ItemMoretti` object and a connection to the ensuing Node.

The `add()` method is responsible for traversing the list to detect the appropriate position alphabetically, where to append the new `Node` by putting it between the most recent and the imminent `Node`. In such way, this implementation manages to preserve the linked list at a fixed and sorted sequence.